# interpolation of 2d data and simulation of background

Tags: python, image-processing, interpolation

I have three column data which I plot below.
Is there a good way to simulate the background? Then I can remove the feature in the middle of the figure.

First remove it.Then do a 2d interpolation.

I have tried python's scipy.interpolate.Rbf and  I am not satisfied with the result.

Is there another choice? I hope there is a better pothonic method.

[image]

Comment: pothonic? Do you mean pythonic?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how accurate you want the reconstructed background to be.

If you want an approximate background which is fast to compute, have a look at algorithms for [background subtraction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Background_subtraction). You should be able to find a method that suits your need.

If you want an accurate background with feature removal followed by texture reconstruction, you can have a look at algorithms for [inpainting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inpainting). These will generally be more computationally intensive and require a precursor step of calculating the approximate background first to locate the foreground object(s).

Comment: Thanks.I choose inpainting. You mean I can remove the feature,say,a retangle and then interpolate the new pixel values  by inpainting ?I should install cv2 or opencv?

Comment: opencv could dig a hole in the image and fix it?My image is just a 2D matrix. Is there any example code of inpaint? It is too brief at [link](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/photo/doc/inpainting.html)

Comment: It could be used to jpg or png files.But my file is just a 3 column data set,x,y and z . cv2 can do that ?